# Datasource control in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datasource, sqldatasource

I worked on `ASP.NET` and I use `SqlDataSource` control to add binding in my `DataGrid`. But now I am making an app in `WPF C#` and there is no `SqlDataSource` in Toolbar. I am using `VS2013`. I searched online and most of the sites tell to add connection manually in c# file. So tell me is there a way to add datasource in WPF C# DataGrid like in ASP.NET DataGrid.

Comment: Can anyone guide me please

Comment: i also tried with entity framework, there is no entitydatasource control in toolbar can anyone help me why these controller are not showing in VS2013